# Is it good practice to re-arrange the nodes of an XML document in XSL?

Tags: xslt

XSL seems to be relatively limited by the ordering of the nodes in the underlying XML.  Is it the intention of XSL to allow you to re-arrange the underlying XML nodes, or is the intention of XSL to have you transform ("style") the nodes in their original structure?

Put another way, is it a best practice to start with XML that represents the final structure, in terms of the nesting and ordering of node representations?  Or is it common to use XSL to completely re-arrange the nodes of an XML document in addition to transforming it?

Comment: It is up to you. Either can be done. It depends on what your desired output is.

Comment: Yes, it's common to use XSLT to completely rearrange the input as part of (not in addition to) the process of transforming it. But of course, if you have the freedom to design your input XML to reduce the amount of transformation that needs to be done, that's a choice you can make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSL collectively refers to XSLT, XSL-FO, and XPath, but your question appears to be focussed primarily on XSLT...

XSLT is fundamentally a transformation language, and rearranging structure is a basic part of transformation.  It's absolutely a best practice to use XSLT to rework structure, oftentimes from one standard XSD to a completely different one.

What you pose as a distinction (style vs structure) is actually a false dichotomy. **Transformation can be, and often is, a key part of styling.**  XML is frequently transformed into HTML (and CSS) for online presentation.  Or, XML is transformed to XSL-FO (and then used to generate PDF) for print presentation.  Or, a transformation is made to vary presentation based on characteristics of the targeted audience.   The list goes on endlessly.

**In short, yes, it's good practice to rearrange nodes of an XML document in XSLT.**